# C programe compile iss

Tags: c

program is not asking the for enter the number. After Entered the number both are printf statements are coming

Do you know the Issue? Or How to fix it. I tried to reinstall the eclipse not showing the result. Also Installed Older Eclipse, but not working.

I am Using windows 11 64 bit OS

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int number;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    // reads and stores input
    scanf("%d", &number);

    // displays output
    printf("You entered: %d", number);  
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run the basic program. But the Result is coming after entered the number. Not printing First print f statement.

```
56

Enter an integer: You entered: 56
```

Comment: Firstly try flushing the output stream: `printf("Enter an integer: "); fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Try flushing `stdout` after the first `printf()`. Or, use `\n` at the end of the string inside the first `printf()`.

Comment: Please do not spam tags and do not abuse formatting. Doing so does brings attention to your question, but only negative one, in form of close votes and downvotes.